# Error: Bad file descriptor, when open() a file

Tags: c, ubuntu-11.04

I want to create a file with name that input by user.

Here is my code:

```
int function1(){

    char path[50];
    char choice_f;
    char choice_m;
    int flag;     <-- updated
    mode_t mode;

    printf("Filename : ");
    scanf("%s", path);
    //printf("%s", path);     <-- path can be shown
    printf("\n");

    printf("Desire flag : ");
    scanf("%c", &choice_f);                 <-- updated
    //printf("%s", path);     <-- path CANNOT be shown from here
    while (choice_f != '1' && choice_f != '2' && choice_f != '3'){
        printf("Invalid input! Flag: ");
        scanf("%c", &choice_f);             <-- updated
    }
    if (choice_f == '1')
        flag = O_RDONLY;                      <-- updated
    else if (choice_f == '2')
        flag = O_WRONLY;                      <-- updated
    else if (choice_f == '3')
        flag = O_RDWR;                    <-- updated

    printf("Desire mode : ");
    scanf("%c", &choice_m);                <-- updated
    while(choice_m != '1' && choice_m != '2' && choice_m != '3' && choice_m != '4'){
        printf("Invalid input! Mode: ");
        scanf("%c", &choice_m);                <-- updated
    }
    if (choice_m == '1')
        mode = S_IRWXU;
    else if (choice_m == '2')
        mode = S_IRWXG;
    else if (choice_m == '3')
        mode = S_IRWXO;
    else if (choice_m == '4')
        mode = S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO;


    int fd = open(path, (int)flag|O_EXCL|O_CREAT);
    fchmod(fd, mode);
    printf("%d", fd);
    if (fd == -1){
        perror("error");
        return 1;
    }else
        printf("File \'%s\' Created \n", path);
    if (close(fd)<0)
        perror("close()");
    return 0;
}
```

But at the end of the program, I get the error message:

```
Error: Bad file descriptor
```

I tested the `path` with several times, and seems like after the second `scanf()`, the `path` cannot be shown. Even I tried to assign the `path` to another variable, it's still the same.

What should I do to solve this error?

Comment: Waaah! You just cast a string to an int! "(int)flag" is clearly very, very bad. I wouldn't expect `open` to do what you want with junk input like that. fd's going to be -1 after that.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &choice_f)` is smashing your stack - you're reading a string into a single character variable.

Comment: To be honest, this is the code done by my friend, and I'm doing the other part and now I'm combining all the functions. So, the error comes out when I try to combine it with others function, but it's work before I combine it. The code is same, but the error appears.

Comment: For future questions, please provide only a minimal example of your problem. In this case, all these multi-line print statements make the code harder to read and are effectively just noise.

Comment: @l4mpi, in my previous post, I posted the major problem, and simplify the code, which totally not used in my code, just the concept, what I get is criticized as bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the only problem but you're setting of choice_f and choice_m is incorrect and should be

```
scanf("%c", &choice_f);
scanf("%c", &choice_m);
```

instead.  i.e. You should use the `%c` format specifier instead.  If you use `%s`, a nul terminator (at the very least) will be written; you haven't provided storage for this so other stack variables will be over-written.

After that, as suggested by Nicholas Wilson, you should change `flags` to be `int` rather than `char*` (and remove the quotes from the assignments to O_RDONLY etc.)

Comment: But I tried to change the `open()` call, to `open("test", (int)flag|O_EXCL|O_CREAT);`, and it's work with the `choice_f` and `choice_m`. But when I change it back the `"test"` to `path`, it's not working anymore.

Comment: I think it might be the scanf for choice_f which over-writes memory for path.  The first char for path may be set to be the nul terminator from the char array you requested be copied into a single char.  Can you try changing the choice_* format specifiers and see if that helps?

Comment: @AnonyNewbie See the update to my answer or Nicholas Wilson's comment to your question for another bug in the code.

Comment: I changed the `flags` to `int`, the assignments to `O_RDONLY` without quotes, and the `scanf()` to `sprintf()` as mentioned, it's show out this error `warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments`.

Comment: @AnonyNewbie I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you post the first line which generates that error please?

Comment: `chin@chin-virtual-machine:~/Desktop$ gcc supercommand.c -o supercommand.o`  
`supercommand.c: In function ‘function1’:`  
`supercommand.c:149:2: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments`  
`supercommand.c:172:2: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments`

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask for the line of (possibly updated) source code...  Can you post this as well please?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20518/discussion-between-simonc-and-anonynewbie)